# How long does it take to transfer data between the main memory and GPU memory?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

GPU's are new to me. This OpenCL snippet says it transferred 7mb to the GPU in 7ms. Does that sound about right or am I missing something?

```
const int dim1Size = 960000;
int* dim1 = new int[dim1Size];
int* dim2 = new int[dim1Size];
long size = sizeof(int)*dim1Size*2;
size = size / 1024 / 1024;
cout << size << "mb to transfer" << endl;

cl_mem mem_d1 = clCreateBuffer(*context, 0, sizeof(int)*dim1Size, NULL, NULL);
cl_mem mem_d2 = clCreateBuffer(*context, 0, sizeof(int)*dim1Size, NULL, NULL);

GetSystemTime(&time);
WORD start = (time.wSecond * 1000) + time.wMilliseconds;
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(*queue, mem_d1, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int)*dim1Size, dim1, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(*queue, mem_d2, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int)*dim1Size, dim2, 0, NULL, NULL);
GetSystemTime(&time);
WORD end = (time.wSecond * 1000) + time.wMilliseconds;
cout << (end - start) << "ms to transfer";
```

Comment: wow! i thought it sounded fast. this is an older work computer so maybe that's why it sounded slow to you.

Comment: actually, doesn't the opencl runtime handle whether or not to use main memory? and so in this case maybe it is never actually transferring to gpu memory?

Comment: PCI-e 3.0 bandwidth is more than 5GB/s so more than 5MB/ms so more than 35MB/7ms but yours is old so pci-e 2.0 its nearly half so 17MB/7ms and you say its 7mb/7ms so it maybe even older pci-e 1.0 so you may be right. If your card supports cl/gl interop then you can do calcs in card so no copy is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1MBps is very slow for any GPU that can run OpenCL.  However, if we look at the numbers a bit closer, we might get a bit different results.

First off, your sample is not pushing 7MB, it's pushing two buffers 3.66MB each.  Together they are 7.32MB, which is not a big difference, but nevertheless is a difference.

However there is a bigger uncertainty in this code.  You're using GetSystemTime().  It reports time with the millisecond precision, but the granularity is not guaranteed.  In fact, if there is no processes that requested higher granularity, you will get up to 55ms accuracy.  This is most likely what's happening with your code.  here is a quick sample that allows you to figure out the current GetSystemTime() granularity:

```
SYSTEMTIME t1, t2;
GetSystemTime(&t1);
do {
    GetSystemTime(&t2);
} while (0 == memcmp(&t1, &t2, sizeof(SYSTEMTIME)));
std::cout << "timer granularity is " << t2.wMilliseconds - t1.wMilliseconds << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
```

Answering your original question, you should see at least ~700MBps System->video memory transfer, even on the very slow kinds of old PCIe v.1.0 cards.